# limit of a fundemental solution

Tags: limits

Is it possible and how can I calculate the limit of $$\\lim_{t \downarrow 0}v(t,x)=t^\frac{-3}{2}e^\frac{-|x|^2}{4t}$$ when $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and  $t>0$? For sure, it's not continuous at 0, so I can't just plug in 0.

Comment: For $|x| > 0 <t$ we have $0< \exp (-|x|^2/4 t)$ $=1/\exp (|x|^2/4 t)$ $<1/[(|x|^2/4 t)^2/2!]=$ $32 t^2/|x|^4.$

Comment: Thx, I understand these equations, but what does it tell me about the limit?

Comment: For $|x|>0<t$ we have  $0<v(t,x)<32 (\sqrt t)/|x|^4.$  Let $t\to 0.$